# Making my JavaScript, which assumes my CSV is two-dimensional, work for one-dimensional CSV instead

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

How do I parse this CSV with JavaScript?

```
1363085391,42.890000000000,5.432200000000
1363088879,47.570000000000,4.981800000000
1363120475,56.560000000000,1.768000000000
1363132522,53.000000000000,1.000000000000
1363214378,48.630000000000,4.000000000000
[...]
```

It shows the [bitcoin price and trade volume history](http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/localbtcCAD.csv.gz) for the Canadian dollar. However, the list is too massive; it shows every trade ever done. So I'm trying to reduce it from hundreds of data points a day to one per week. Basically "monotizing" the data points into time span intervals by adding up the volume and averaging the price. This way, with simpler data, the line in [my line chart](https://jsfiddle.net/qmuax5ot/) is expected to look a whole lot better.

Unfortunately the script won't work; it assumes the CSV is a two-dimensional array, but in reality I think it's only one-dimensional? How do I change it so it parses the CSV properly?

```js
function simplifyData(data_set) {
  interval_length = 3600; // hourly intervals

  last_price = 0;
  idx = 0;
  while (idx < data_set.length) {

    // reset value for this interval
    volume = 0;
    price_sum = 0;
    count = 0;
    timestamp = data_set[idx]['timestamp'] + interval_length;

    // get sums for this interval
    while (data_set[idx]['timetamp'] < timestamp) {
      volume += data_set[idx]['volume'];
      price_sum += data_set[idx]['price'];
      count++;
      idx++;
      if (idx >= data_set.length)
        break;
    }

    // get average price
    price = count > 0 ? price_sum / count : last_price;
    last_price = price;

    // add new row to monotized data array
    monotized_data.append([
      timestamp: timestamp,
      volume: volume,
      price: price
    ]);
  }
}

// Format: time (UNIX timestamp), price, amount traded
// http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/localbtcCAD.csv.gz
var complexCadCsv = "1363085391,42.890000000000,5.432200000000
1363088879,47.570000000000,4.981800000000
1363120475,56.560000000000,1.768000000000
1363132522,53.000000000000,1.000000000000
1363214378,48.630000000000,4.000000000000
1363217281,48.770000000000,2.000200000000
1363223157,48.860000000000,2.046500000000
1363232051,49.110000000000,4.235500000000
1363272551,54.250000000000,1.000000000000
1363283662,49.780000000000,5.925600000000
1363293072,55.500000000000,1.027000000000
1363321440,56.000000000000,5.357100000000
1363346950,55.220000000000,7.016900000000
1363379555,55.600000000000,4.945900000000
1363379607,55.740000000000,1.000000000000
1363381362,49.220000000000,0.101600000000
1363382662,49.220000000000,4.896100000000
1363391161,55.380000000000,2.000000000000
1363401704,56.060000000000,1.000000000000
1363467393,56.000000000000,0.892900000000
1363496639,56.700000000000,1.500100000000
1363524530,56.930000000000,6.000100000000
1363527377,56.900000000000,6.497900000000
1363542700,56.000000000000,2.142900000000
1363547113,55.000000000000,3.000000000000
1363564084,57.040000000000,2.156400000000
1363638453,57.880000000000,0.331700000000
1363729323,70.000000000000,0.857100000000
1363740718,73.070000000000,0.136800000000
1363795449,63.450000000000,1.000000000000
1363795494,63.860000000000,1.000100000000
1363795603,63.430000000000,0.157700000000
1363798700,68.390000000000,1.462200000000
1363800835,68.180000000000,1.991300000000
1363803497,67.940000000000,1.014600000000
1363803790,68.160000000000,1.027100000000
1363814790,69.580000000000,1.050000000000
1363814810,68.270000000000,0.929400000000
1363825583,68.250000000000,5.230600000000
1363829358,78.000000000000,1.050000000000
1363836583,83.300000000000,2.999800000000
1363837642,84.000000000000,2.000000000000
1363895966,75.410000000000,0.663000000000
1363944788,75.000000000000,4.000000000000
1363984884,90.000000000000,1.111100000000
1363987472,90.000000000000,1.111100000000
1363988438,89.350000000000,0.074000000000
1363989586,85.090000000000,1.999900000000
1364000191,88.000000000000,1.000000000000
1364002717,85.230000000000,1.490100000000
1364010104,70.730000000000,1.000000000000
1364013267,86.000000000000,1.162800000000
1364073182,78.000000000000,3.900000000000
1364089933,80.000000000000,3.025000000000
1364249509,74.360000000000,1.485600000000
1364262262,89.550000000000,1.116700000000
1364265293,90.040000000000,1.055000000000
1364310351,92.450000000000,1.081700000000
1364334487,81.210000000000,1.994800000000
1364355951,94.630000000000,1.420000000000
1364357864,95.380000000000,1.048400000000
1364358542,94.800000000000,1.054900000000
1364364067,82.820000000000,13.219800000000
1364395451,99.100000000000,0.100900000000
1364400184,102.700000000000,1.000000000000
1364401183,100.570000000000,1.093800000000
1364403945,101.420000000000,1.000000000000
1364411110,101.720000000000,0.498800000000
1364436263,106.740000000000,1.799900000000
1364436873,94.960000000000,1.000000000000
1364437451,94.520000000000,0.999900000000
1364440483,104.190000000000,0.499900000000
1364489123,109.760000000000,1.047800000000
1364490688,109.730000000000,1.000000000000
1364494732,100.230000000000,1.000000000000
1364498537,95.620000000000,1.950000000000
1364502332,95.780000000000,1.200700000000
1364505883,99.490000000000,0.251300000000
1364513250,103.900000000000,0.517100000000
1364516343,83.470000000000,1.018300000000
1364573738,97.140000000000,0.257400000000
1364580938,95.700000000000,1.000000000000
1364598407,102.000000000000,1.000000000000
1364600233,102.000000000000,1.000000000000
1364601641,102.000000000000,1.010000000000
1364605133,105.000000000000,1.000000000000
1364709921,99.880000000000,1.000000000000
1364712798,99.990000000000,1.000100000000
1364748894,101.470000000000,1.000000000000
1364755340,100.590000000000,3.000000000000
1364792969,106.000000000000,1.000000000000
1364799933,102.400000000000,1.000000000000
1364800923,101.560000000000,1.000000000000
1364828813,112.000000000000,2.000000000000
1364832014,115.000000000000,5.000000000000
1364832308,115.000000000000,3.000000000000
1364834249,112.720000000000,5.855000000000
1364838578,115.240000000000,5.727400000000
1364841672,104.360000000000,12.457200000000
1364923361,120.900000000000,2.999900000000
1364936087,120.710000000000,4.970600000000
1364948998,124.810000000000,4.999800000000
1364959661,127.170000000000,0.995000000000
1364965648,121.770000000000,1.000000000000
1364973827,136.060000000000,1.000000000000
1364974001,147.890000000000,4.000100000000
1364998794,140.320000000000,3.563200000000
1365026364,123.790000000000,1.015400000000
1365027711,127.780000000000,6.260900000000
1365046987,138.360000000000,4.000000000000
1365057275,138.500000000000,5.499900000000
1365065898,157.040000000000,1.999400000000
1365090058,145.220000000000,5.509000000000
1365104881,164.890000000000,5.458200000000
1365105565,139.710000000000,1.250000000000
1365138055,145.850000000000,1.849900000000
1365167322,166.250000000000,0.601500000000
1365173858,146.080000000000,1.999900000000
1365174283,148.260000000000,0.134900000000
1365183486,149.890000000000,3.000100000000
1365184905,161.740000000000,2.000100000000
1365205476,152.790000000000,1.000000000000
1365210365,175.000000000000,1.000000000000
1365219395,150.960000000000,0.999700000000
1365220927,150.910000000000,1.000000000000
1365268452,153.390000000000,0.652000000000
1365272285,170.000000000000,1.000000000000
1365274795,170.000000000000,1.000000000000
1365278764,170.000000000000,1.000000000000
1365278930,154.030000000000,0.519400000000
1365280374,170.000000000000,1.000000000000
1365281909,154.560000000000,0.650000000000
1365283450,170.000000000000,1.000000000000
1365287835,170.000000000000,1.541200000000
1365303267,153.940000000000,3.500100000000
1365312742,155.620000000000,0.128500000000
1365325139,161.570000000000,3.000000000000
1365349680,169.230000000000,2.000000000000
1365354798,138.110000000000,1.010000000000
1365356226,180.190000000000,1.664900000000
1365362290,174.010000000000,0.287300000000
1365377549,173.640000000000,2.000000000000
1365379774,175.010000000000,1.000000000000
1365384562,179.980000000000,2.222500000000
1365396478,183.290000000000,2.000000000000
1365434139,203.850000000000,0.098100000000
1365434614,208.360000000000,1.000000000000
1365437520,197.620000000000,2.000000000000
1365440837,195.520000000000,4.000000000000
1365449254,197.610000000000,4.000000000000
1365467994,202.160000000000,2.990500000000
1365469985,202.160000000000,1.500200000000
1365478982,206.360000000000,0.997700000000
1365479416,206.220000000000,1.000000000000
1365479554,203.290000000000,1.000000000000
1365486039,207.860000000000,0.465300000000
1365500973,219.210000000000,2.280900000000
1365518766,228.930000000000,1.970100000000
1365518846,225.910000000000,0.996000000000
1365520063,229.770000000000,0.747300000000
1365521859,235.270000000000,3.000000000000
1365521926,235.270000000000,0.850100000000
1365524515,240.510000000000,3.326200000000
1365524659,235.400000000000,0.999100000000
1365526701,238.440000000000,1.000000000000
1365527072,242.330000000000,2.000000000000
1365527199,240.510000000000,1.309700000000
1365529148,251.570000000000,1.000000000000
1365537800,265.560000000000,1.000000000000
1365542522,305.000000000000,1.508200000000
1365542586,305.000000000000,1.893400000000
1365551390,335.650000000000,0.715000000000
1365554253,265.540000000000,1.000000000000
1365558982,284.240000000000,1.000000000000
1365563330,306.440000000000,0.326300000000
1365566909,310.950000000000,0.064300000000
1365578721,338.530000000000,1.181600000000
1365606252,273.660000000000,1.000000000000
1365610294,281.800000000000,2.129200000000
1365612809,265.810000000000,2.000000000000
1365618499,262.140000000000,1.000000000000
1365628947,250.000000000000,1.944000000000
1365629291,253.640000000000,1.182800000000
1365642148,151.740000000000,2.000000000000
1365642413,141.270000000000,2.000000000000
1365678778,188.540000000000,3.993100000000
1365703940,148.580000000000,4.455400000000
1365716351,151.650000000000,0.680000000000
1365717197,136.400000000000,1.000000000000
1365717771,122.450000000000,1.951800000000
1365724442,124.000000000000,2.000000000000
1365773281,117.460000000000,1.251500000000
1365773887,121.000000000000,1.991800000000
1365776714,122.360000000000,2.231100000000
1365795875,114.590000000000,1.000000000000
1365796323,115.000000000000,2.000000000000
1365798963,106.190000000000,2.000000000000
1365802678,106.180000000000,1.000000000000
1365804038,111.410000000000,1.790000000000
1365810280,109.980000000000,1.500000000000
1365811712,115.000000000000,2.000000000000
1365813104,109.970000000000,1.000000000000
1365816966,165.200000000000,3.026600000000
1365819572,150.000000000000,1.066700000000
1365820699,128.730000000000,1.649900000000
1365823425,124.060000000000,3.224400000000
1365826775,150.000000000000,1.066700000000
1365877655,150.000000000000,2.000000000000
1365878739,159.330000000000,2.008500000000
1365884739,150.000000000000,4.000000000000
1365888397,150.000000000000,3.000000000000
1365956959,150.000000000000,5.330000000000
1365961896,140.000000000000,0.535700000000
1365979939,142.140000000000,1.000000000000
1365991144,128.990000000000,2.000000000000
1365993080,150.000000000000,1.333300000000
1366014910,135.000000000000,4.444400000000
1366022593,149.640000000000,0.467800000000
1366044482,123.500000000000,3.029100000000
1366045307,119.750000000000,1.002100000000
1366048928,119.750000000000,0.668100000000
1366055142,109.990000000000,0.181800000000
1366062216,109.480000000000,1.080000000000
1366065512,100.000000000000,0.181000000000
1366085870,88.150000000000,1.000000000000
1366085948,91.540000000000,0.436900000000
1366097421,74.700000000000,10.495300000000
1366129928,96.000000000000,2.083300000000
1366130124,99.720000000000,4.000000000000
1366133447,99.890000000000,1.000000000000
1366135520,103.730000000000,1.100000000000
1366138028,95.390000000000,1.100000000000
1366144237,69.480000000000,1.511300000000
1366145377,75.000000000000,2.586700000000
1366155682,89.800000000000,2.000000000000
1366158005,88.800000000000,1.000000000000
1366158456,89.800000000000,1.993300000000
1366164776,94.000000000000,2.000000000000
1366173698,102.640000000000,1.997400000000
1366198863,103.450000000000,1.991400000000
1366211035,102.450000000000,2.196200000000
1366218782,94.000000000000,3.000000000000
1366225431,94.000000000000,2.042600000000
1366233216,214.470000000000,1.000000000000
1366318951,108.730000000000,0.919700000000
1366387777,129.690000000000,1.982200000000
1366394307,135.420000000000,0.184600000000
1366413885,134.140000000000,0.298200000000
1366551162,136.710000000000,0.129600000000
1366553999,140.700000000000,2.487500000000
1366620334,137.830000000000,0.420800000000
1366671189,107.380000000000,1.500000000000
1366684569,141.740000000000,1.000000000000
1366686872,142.090000000000,1.055600000000
1366687106,142.130000000000,1.759000000000
1366746322,148.230000000000,3.373100000000
1366825778,159.250000000000,0.125600000000
1366903154,166.040000000000,1.540000000000
1366903247,168.230000000000,0.118900000000
1366906417,165.440000000000,1.588300000000
1366906495,166.300000000000,1.000000000000
1366912064,164.670000000000,2.130000000000
1366914573,164.820000000000,0.182000000000
1366978559,143.290000000000,1.395800000000
1367001597,144.390000000000,1.038900000000
1367002599,165.650000000000,1.000000000000
1367024672,142.890000000000,0.810000000000
1367027540,144.780000000000,1.450500000000
1367027692,146.310000000000,2.000000000000
1367029695,143.800000000000,0.750000000000
1367034952,143.800000000000,3.129500000000
1367043181,143.710000000000,2.261500000000
1367085501,141.190000000000,1.416600000000
1367100612,155.680000000000,1.281900000000
1367182014,170.140000000000,1.000000000000
1367182173,169.720000000000,1.119500000000
1367186205,170.710000000000,1.000000000000
1367275779,153.550000000000,1.465300000000
1367289143,198.350000000000,6.049900000000
1367323428,197.180000000000,7.000000000000
1367331486,155.660000000000,1.606000000000
1367348392,189.950000000000,5.264600000000
1367351603,146.060000000000,2.998800000000
1367356384,188.010000000000,7.138000000000
1367364586,167.170000000000,0.179500000000
1367364740,191.010000000000,7.853000000000
1367378952,165.000000000000,1.818200000000
1367423338,142.430000000000,3.931900000000
1367446179,133.240000000000,2.251600000000
1367457397,131.820000000000,1.273400000000
1367474137,129.410000000000,0.390000000000
1367506472,125.970000000000,0.079400000000
1367517588,112.580000000000,4.441400000000
1367534445,116.880000000000,0.171100000000
1367562381,108.910000000000,0.550900000000
1367591999,106.120000000000,0.471200000000
1367595257,104.460000000000,0.478600000000
1367599098,144.030000000000,1.041500000000
1367604271,99.230000000000,2.962700000000
1367625410,103.810000000000,2.022900000000"

var finalOutput = simplifyData(complexCadCsv);

$(".new_csv").append(finalOutput);
```

```html
<!--<script src="https://rawgit.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv/master/src/jquery.csv.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>New simplified CSV</h1>
<div class="new_csv"></div>
```

Comment: You have rows and columns isn't it two dimensional?

Comment: I don't know. It's what the guy who gave me the code said. You can check it out if you want to: https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/6ul8y3/where_do_i_download_bitcoins_price_history_as_xls/dmi3kmg/

Comment: What is `monotized_data`? The comment says it's an array, but there's no `append` method on arrays. It's called `push` in Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data_set` is a string, but `simplifyData()` is access it as if it's an array of objects. You need to convert it first.

```
data_set = data_set.split('\n').map(line => {
    var linearray = line.split(',');
    return {
        timestamp: parseInt(linearray[0], 10),
        price: parseFloat(linearray[1]),
        volume: parseFloat(linearray[2])
    };
});
```

And in your call to `monotized_data.append`, you have square brackets when you should have curly braces, and you should be calling `push()`

```
    monotized_data.push({
      timestamp: timestamp,
      volume: volume,
      price: price
    });
```

```js
function simplifyData(data_set) {
  interval_length = 3600; // hourly intervals

  last_price = 0;
  idx = 0;
  
  monotized_data = []
    
  while (idx < data_set.length) {

    // reset value for this interval
    volume = 0;
    price_sum = 0;
    count = 0;
    
    // Format: time (UNIX timestamp), price, amount traded
    //   timestamp: data_set[idx][0]
    //   price:     data_set[idx][1]
    //   volume:    data_set[idx][2]
    
    timestamp = data_set[idx][0] + interval_length;

    // get sums for this interval
    while (data_set[idx][0] < timestamp) {
      volume += data_set[idx][2];
      price_sum += data_set[idx][1];
      count++;
      idx++;
      if (idx >= data_set.length)
        break;
    }

    // get average price
    price = count > 0 ? price_sum / count : last_price;
    last_price = price;

    // add new row to monotized data array
    monotized_data.push({
      timestamp: timestamp,
      volume: volume,
      price: price
    });
  }
}

// Format: time (UNIX timestamp), price, amount traded
// http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/localbtcCAD.csv.gz
var complexCadCsv = `1363085391,42.890000000000,5.432200000000
1363088879, 47.570000000000, 4.981800000000
1363120475, 56.560000000000, 1.768000000000
1363132522, 53.000000000000, 1.000000000000
1363214378, 48.630000000000, 4.000000000000
1363217281, 48.770000000000, 2.000200000000
1363223157, 48.860000000000, 2.046500000000
1363232051, 49.110000000000, 4.235500000000
1363272551, 54.250000000000, 1.000000000000
1363283662, 49.780000000000, 5.925600000000
1363293072, 55.500000000000, 1.027000000000
1363321440, 56.000000000000, 5.357100000000
1363346950, 55.220000000000, 7.016900000000
1363379555, 55.600000000000, 4.945900000000
1363379607, 55.740000000000, 1.000000000000
1363381362, 49.220000000000, 0.101600000000
1363382662, 49.220000000000, 4.896100000000
1363391161, 55.380000000000, 2.000000000000
1363401704, 56.060000000000, 1.000000000000
1363467393, 56.000000000000, 0.892900000000
1363496639, 56.700000000000, 1.500100000000
1363524530, 56.930000000000, 6.000100000000
1363527377, 56.900000000000, 6.497900000000
1363542700, 56.000000000000, 2.142900000000
1363547113, 55.000000000000, 3.000000000000
1363564084, 57.040000000000, 2.156400000000
1363638453, 57.880000000000, 0.331700000000
1363729323, 70.000000000000, 0.857100000000
1363740718, 73.070000000000, 0.136800000000
1363795449, 63.450000000000, 1.000000000000
1363795494, 63.860000000000, 1.000100000000
1363795603, 63.430000000000, 0.157700000000
1363798700, 68.390000000000, 1.462200000000
1363800835, 68.180000000000, 1.991300000000
1363803497, 67.940000000000, 1.014600000000
1363803790, 68.160000000000, 1.027100000000
1363814790, 69.580000000000, 1.050000000000
1363814810, 68.270000000000, 0.929400000000
1363825583, 68.250000000000, 5.230600000000
1363829358, 78.000000000000, 1.050000000000
1363836583, 83.300000000000, 2.999800000000
1363837642, 84.000000000000, 2.000000000000
1363895966, 75.410000000000, 0.663000000000
1363944788, 75.000000000000, 4.000000000000
1363984884, 90.000000000000, 1.111100000000
1363987472, 90.000000000000, 1.111100000000
1363988438, 89.350000000000, 0.074000000000
1363989586, 85.090000000000, 1.999900000000
1364000191, 88.000000000000, 1.000000000000
1364002717, 85.230000000000, 1.490100000000
1364010104, 70.730000000000, 1.000000000000
1364013267, 86.000000000000, 1.162800000000
1364073182, 78.000000000000, 3.900000000000
1364089933, 80.000000000000, 3.025000000000
1364249509, 74.360000000000, 1.485600000000
1364262262, 89.550000000000, 1.116700000000
1364265293, 90.040000000000, 1.055000000000
1364310351, 92.450000000000, 1.081700000000
1364334487, 81.210000000000, 1.994800000000
1364355951, 94.630000000000, 1.420000000000
1364357864, 95.380000000000, 1.048400000000
1364358542, 94.800000000000, 1.054900000000
1364364067, 82.820000000000, 13.219800000000
1364395451, 99.100000000000, 0.100900000000
1364400184, 102.700000000000, 1.000000000000
1364401183, 100.570000000000, 1.093800000000
1364403945, 101.420000000000, 1.000000000000
1364411110, 101.720000000000, 0.498800000000
1364436263, 106.740000000000, 1.799900000000
1364436873, 94.960000000000, 1.000000000000
1364437451, 94.520000000000, 0.999900000000
1364440483, 104.190000000000, 0.499900000000
1364489123, 109.760000000000, 1.047800000000
1364490688, 109.730000000000, 1.000000000000
1364494732, 100.230000000000, 1.000000000000
1364498537, 95.620000000000, 1.950000000000
1364502332, 95.780000000000, 1.200700000000
1364505883, 99.490000000000, 0.251300000000
1364513250, 103.900000000000, 0.517100000000
1364516343, 83.470000000000, 1.018300000000
1364573738, 97.140000000000, 0.257400000000
1364580938, 95.700000000000, 1.000000000000
1364598407, 102.000000000000, 1.000000000000
1364600233, 102.000000000000, 1.000000000000
1364601641, 102.000000000000, 1.010000000000
1364605133, 105.000000000000, 1.000000000000
1364709921, 99.880000000000, 1.000000000000
1364712798, 99.990000000000, 1.000100000000
1364748894, 101.470000000000, 1.000000000000
1364755340, 100.590000000000, 3.000000000000
1364792969, 106.000000000000, 1.000000000000
1364799933, 102.400000000000, 1.000000000000
1364800923, 101.560000000000, 1.000000000000
1364828813, 112.000000000000, 2.000000000000
1364832014, 115.000000000000, 5.000000000000
1364832308, 115.000000000000, 3.000000000000
1364834249, 112.720000000000, 5.855000000000
1364838578, 115.240000000000, 5.727400000000
1364841672, 104.360000000000, 12.457200000000
1364923361, 120.900000000000, 2.999900000000
1364936087, 120.710000000000, 4.970600000000
1364948998, 124.810000000000, 4.999800000000
1364959661, 127.170000000000, 0.995000000000
1364965648, 121.770000000000, 1.000000000000
1364973827, 136.060000000000, 1.000000000000
1364974001, 147.890000000000, 4.000100000000
1364998794, 140.320000000000, 3.563200000000
1365026364, 123.790000000000, 1.015400000000
1365027711, 127.780000000000, 6.260900000000
1365046987, 138.360000000000, 4.000000000000
1365057275, 138.500000000000, 5.499900000000
1365065898, 157.040000000000, 1.999400000000
1365090058, 145.220000000000, 5.509000000000
1365104881, 164.890000000000, 5.458200000000
1365105565, 139.710000000000, 1.250000000000
1365138055, 145.850000000000, 1.849900000000
1365167322, 166.250000000000, 0.601500000000
1365173858, 146.080000000000, 1.999900000000
1365174283, 148.260000000000, 0.134900000000
1365183486, 149.890000000000, 3.000100000000
1365184905, 161.740000000000, 2.000100000000
1365205476, 152.790000000000, 1.000000000000
1365210365, 175.000000000000, 1.000000000000
1365219395, 150.960000000000, 0.999700000000
1365220927, 150.910000000000, 1.000000000000
1365268452, 153.390000000000, 0.652000000000
1365272285, 170.000000000000, 1.000000000000
1365274795, 170.000000000000, 1.000000000000
1365278764, 170.000000000000, 1.000000000000
1365278930, 154.030000000000, 0.519400000000
1365280374, 170.000000000000, 1.000000000000
1365281909, 154.560000000000, 0.650000000000
1365283450, 170.000000000000, 1.000000000000
1365287835, 170.000000000000, 1.541200000000
1365303267, 153.940000000000, 3.500100000000
1365312742, 155.620000000000, 0.128500000000
1365325139, 161.570000000000, 3.000000000000
1365349680, 169.230000000000, 2.000000000000
1365354798, 138.110000000000, 1.010000000000
1365356226, 180.190000000000, 1.664900000000
1365362290, 174.010000000000, 0.287300000000
1365377549, 173.640000000000, 2.000000000000
1365379774, 175.010000000000, 1.000000000000
1365384562, 179.980000000000, 2.222500000000
1365396478, 183.290000000000, 2.000000000000
1365434139, 203.850000000000, 0.098100000000
1365434614, 208.360000000000, 1.000000000000
1365437520, 197.620000000000, 2.000000000000
1365440837, 195.520000000000, 4.000000000000
1365449254, 197.610000000000, 4.000000000000
1365467994, 202.160000000000, 2.990500000000
1365469985, 202.160000000000, 1.500200000000
1365478982, 206.360000000000, 0.997700000000
1365479416, 206.220000000000, 1.000000000000
1365479554, 203.290000000000, 1.000000000000
1365486039, 207.860000000000, 0.465300000000
1365500973, 219.210000000000, 2.280900000000
1365518766, 228.930000000000, 1.970100000000
1365518846, 225.910000000000, 0.996000000000
1365520063, 229.770000000000, 0.747300000000
1365521859, 235.270000000000, 3.000000000000
1365521926, 235.270000000000, 0.850100000000
1365524515, 240.510000000000, 3.326200000000
1365524659, 235.400000000000, 0.999100000000
1365526701, 238.440000000000, 1.000000000000
1365527072, 242.330000000000, 2.000000000000
1365527199, 240.510000000000, 1.309700000000
1365529148, 251.570000000000, 1.000000000000
1365537800, 265.560000000000, 1.000000000000
1365542522, 305.000000000000, 1.508200000000
1365542586, 305.000000000000, 1.893400000000
1365551390, 335.650000000000, 0.715000000000
1365554253, 265.540000000000, 1.000000000000
1365558982, 284.240000000000, 1.000000000000
1365563330, 306.440000000000, 0.326300000000
1365566909, 310.950000000000, 0.064300000000
1365578721, 338.530000000000, 1.181600000000
1365606252, 273.660000000000, 1.000000000000
1365610294, 281.800000000000, 2.129200000000
1365612809, 265.810000000000, 2.000000000000
1365618499, 262.140000000000, 1.000000000000
1365628947, 250.000000000000, 1.944000000000
1365629291, 253.640000000000, 1.182800000000
1365642148, 151.740000000000, 2.000000000000
1365642413, 141.270000000000, 2.000000000000
1365678778, 188.540000000000, 3.993100000000
1365703940, 148.580000000000, 4.455400000000
1365716351, 151.650000000000, 0.680000000000
1365717197, 136.400000000000, 1.000000000000
1365717771, 122.450000000000, 1.951800000000
1365724442, 124.000000000000, 2.000000000000
1365773281, 117.460000000000, 1.251500000000
1365773887, 121.000000000000, 1.991800000000
1365776714, 122.360000000000, 2.231100000000
1365795875, 114.590000000000, 1.000000000000
1365796323, 115.000000000000, 2.000000000000
1365798963, 106.190000000000, 2.000000000000
1365802678, 106.180000000000, 1.000000000000
1365804038, 111.410000000000, 1.790000000000
1365810280, 109.980000000000, 1.500000000000
1365811712, 115.000000000000, 2.000000000000
1365813104, 109.970000000000, 1.000000000000
1365816966, 165.200000000000, 3.026600000000
1365819572, 150.000000000000, 1.066700000000
1365820699, 128.730000000000, 1.649900000000
1365823425, 124.060000000000, 3.224400000000
1365826775, 150.000000000000, 1.066700000000
1365877655, 150.000000000000, 2.000000000000
1365878739, 159.330000000000, 2.008500000000
1365884739, 150.000000000000, 4.000000000000
1365888397, 150.000000000000, 3.000000000000
1365956959, 150.000000000000, 5.330000000000
1365961896, 140.000000000000, 0.535700000000
1365979939, 142.140000000000, 1.000000000000
1365991144, 128.990000000000, 2.000000000000
1365993080, 150.000000000000, 1.333300000000
1366014910, 135.000000000000, 4.444400000000
1366022593, 149.640000000000, 0.467800000000
1366044482, 123.500000000000, 3.029100000000
1366045307, 119.750000000000, 1.002100000000
1366048928, 119.750000000000, 0.668100000000
1366055142, 109.990000000000, 0.181800000000
1366062216, 109.480000000000, 1.080000000000
1366065512, 100.000000000000, 0.181000000000
1366085870, 88.150000000000, 1.000000000000
1366085948, 91.540000000000, 0.436900000000
1366097421, 74.700000000000, 10.495300000000
1366129928, 96.000000000000, 2.083300000000
1366130124, 99.720000000000, 4.000000000000
1366133447, 99.890000000000, 1.000000000000
1366135520, 103.730000000000, 1.100000000000
1366138028, 95.390000000000, 1.100000000000
1366144237, 69.480000000000, 1.511300000000
1366145377, 75.000000000000, 2.586700000000
1366155682, 89.800000000000, 2.000000000000
1366158005, 88.800000000000, 1.000000000000
1366158456, 89.800000000000, 1.993300000000
1366164776, 94.000000000000, 2.000000000000
1366173698, 102.640000000000, 1.997400000000
1366198863, 103.450000000000, 1.991400000000
1366211035, 102.450000000000, 2.196200000000
1366218782, 94.000000000000, 3.000000000000
1366225431, 94.000000000000, 2.042600000000
1366233216, 214.470000000000, 1.000000000000
1366318951, 108.730000000000, 0.919700000000
1366387777, 129.690000000000, 1.982200000000
1366394307, 135.420000000000, 0.184600000000
1366413885, 134.140000000000, 0.298200000000
1366551162, 136.710000000000, 0.129600000000
1366553999, 140.700000000000, 2.487500000000
1366620334, 137.830000000000, 0.420800000000
1366671189, 107.380000000000, 1.500000000000
1366684569, 141.740000000000, 1.000000000000
1366686872, 142.090000000000, 1.055600000000
1366687106, 142.130000000000, 1.759000000000
1366746322, 148.230000000000, 3.373100000000
1366825778, 159.250000000000, 0.125600000000
1366903154, 166.040000000000, 1.540000000000
1366903247, 168.230000000000, 0.118900000000
1366906417, 165.440000000000, 1.588300000000
1366906495, 166.300000000000, 1.000000000000
1366912064, 164.670000000000, 2.130000000000
1366914573, 164.820000000000, 0.182000000000
1366978559, 143.290000000000, 1.395800000000
1367001597, 144.390000000000, 1.038900000000
1367002599, 165.650000000000, 1.000000000000
1367024672, 142.890000000000, 0.810000000000
1367027540, 144.780000000000, 1.450500000000
1367027692, 146.310000000000, 2.000000000000
1367029695, 143.800000000000, 0.750000000000
1367034952, 143.800000000000, 3.129500000000
1367043181, 143.710000000000, 2.261500000000
1367085501, 141.190000000000, 1.416600000000
1367100612, 155.680000000000, 1.281900000000
1367182014, 170.140000000000, 1.000000000000
1367182173, 169.720000000000, 1.119500000000
1367186205, 170.710000000000, 1.000000000000
1367275779, 153.550000000000, 1.465300000000
1367289143, 198.350000000000, 6.049900000000
1367323428, 197.180000000000, 7.000000000000
1367331486, 155.660000000000, 1.606000000000
1367348392, 189.950000000000, 5.264600000000
1367351603, 146.060000000000, 2.998800000000
1367356384, 188.010000000000, 7.138000000000
1367364586, 167.170000000000, 0.179500000000
1367364740, 191.010000000000, 7.853000000000
1367378952, 165.000000000000, 1.818200000000
1367423338, 142.430000000000, 3.931900000000
1367446179, 133.240000000000, 2.251600000000
1367457397, 131.820000000000, 1.273400000000
1367474137, 129.410000000000, 0.390000000000
1367506472, 125.970000000000, 0.079400000000
1367517588, 112.580000000000, 4.441400000000
1367534445, 116.880000000000, 0.171100000000
1367562381, 108.910000000000, 0.550900000000
1367591999, 106.120000000000, 0.471200000000
1367595257, 104.460000000000, 0.478600000000
1367599098, 144.030000000000, 1.041500000000
1367604271, 99.230000000000, 2.962700000000
1367625410, 103.810000000000, 2.022900000000`

// Parse the multi-line CSV string above into a 2D array
var complexCadCsvArray = $.csv.toArrays(complexCadCsv);

// jquery-csv `toArrays` are strings, needs to be number

// Trim whitespace and then convert to Number
var complexCadCsvJsArrayNumbers = complexCadCsvArray.map(row => row.map(el => Number(el.trim())));

// Reduce trade times to same-sized intervals
simplifyData(complexCadCsvJsArrayNumbers);

$(".new_csv").text($.csv.fromObjects(monotized_data));

// ----------
$(".existing_csv").append(complexCadCsvArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv/master/src/jquery.csv.min.js"></script>
<h1>New simplified CSV</h1>
<pre class="new_csv"></pre>
<h1>Existing CSV run through <a href="https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv">jquery-csv</a></h1>
<pre class="existing_csv"></pre>
```

Comment: I was missing a `}`, fixed it.

Comment: Do you bother to read the error messages in the console? You can't have line breaks in a string literal.

Comment: You also never define the variable `monotized_data`.

Comment: I moved https://jsfiddle.net/c5c130fw/9/ locally so it would be easier to debug -- appears I'm getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` when attempting to define the `complexCadCsv` variable. Also did you mean I should initialize an empty array like this `monotized_data = []`? I feel so silly, pardon my stupid questions.

Comment: You can't have unescaped line breaks in a string literal. Put `\n\ ` at the end of each line of that string. This is basic JS syntax, nothing to do with CSV. It won't be an issue if you're reading from a file in the real code.

Comment: Is it `\n\` spelled out or is it a special character? I'm getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`. https://jsfiddle.net/c5c130fw/10/

Comment: I was wrong, you can't escape the newline with `\ ` at the end of the line. So you need to split up the string as `"line 1\n" + "line 2\n" + ...`. And if you're going to do that, you might as well just make it an array in the first place: `[ "line 1", "line 2", ...]`.

Comment: This is all incidental to the logic of parsing the CSV. In the real application, aren't you loading the file using AJAX, not hard-coding it into the script?

Comment: I either have to hardcode or load the file locally. I came across https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv/ the other day, any chance it could be of use?

Comment: Isn't this dynamically changing data, so you need to load it from an API? Anyway, if you hard-code it why don't you just code it as an array of objects, instead of CSV format?

Comment: Yup, it is dynamic but unfortunately it's also a tarball :) (http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/localbtcCAD.csv.gz). I've made some progress here: https://jsfiddle.net/askhflajsf/qg0y2a4t/ -- turns out instead of `\n\`` we just had to wrap the CSV in `...`. Hopefully now we're much closer!

Comment: Yeah, I don't generally mention ES6 template strings, since they may not be supported by all browsers yet. BTW, backticks don't show up in comments, since they're used for code markup.

Comment: Haha, I was wondering why that was! Anyway if you'd be as kind as to see https://jsfiddle.net/askhflajsf/qg0y2a4t/ now. jquery-csv seems to do the job nicely (I kept your code as well), the real problem is somewhere inside `simplifyData` now I think? I can't tell because my browser crashes when I uncomment it.

Comment: `simplifyData` expects the argument to be an array of objects, but `$.csv.toArrays()` creates a 2-dimensional array. So `data_set[idx]['timestamp']` should be `data_set[idx][0]`, for instance.

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/askhflajsf/qg0y2a4t/ -- I'm not getting any errors this time but it doesn't seem to work either so.

Comment: What result are you expecting? You push all the objects onto `monotized_data`, but never do anything with that variable afterward.

Comment: I see. I guess I'm expecting it to append the new CSV to the div. I've updated https://jsfiddle.net/askhflajsf/qg0y2a4t/ -- do I call monotized_data like that?

Comment: You have `monotized_data = []` inside the loop, so you're emptying the array every time you add the next element to it. That should be before the loop.

Comment: You should probably use `$.csv` to convert `monotized_data` from an array to a CSV. Also, the CSV created by `$.csv.toArrays` creates an array of strings, not numbers. You need to parse them before you use them in arithmetic statements. You also need to trim off the spaced before parsing them.

Comment: I've tried following your suggestions, but currently having an issue with the space trimming: https://jsfiddle.net/askhflajsf/qg0y2a4t/15/ -- which is weird because .replace should work right? It works in this reduced test case: https://jsfiddle.net/askhflajsf/0qynqzLc/

Comment: You can't call `.replace()` on an array. You need to use `.map()` twice, once for the rows, and then for the elements in the rows. I've posted a working answer that shows how to do this.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, thank you very much Barmar! If I can ever return the favor, please let me know!